# produce a Google sheet script to disable download, print and copy for editors

Tags: google-sheets

Any way to produce a Google sheet script to disable download, print and copy for editors? Reason: The sheet will need protected (non editable) tabs and ranges, but needs to be shared to all with edit rights to be able to edit nonprotected cells, i.e. dropdowns to interact with the protected data and to be able to change views/graphs. But the sheet as such shouldn't be downloadable or copyable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through scripts or otherwise. There is no way to give edit privileges, but restrict copying of entire sheet.